# Alternative configurations in Gradle for compiling Java

Tags: gradle

With Gradle there are some default configurations such as compile, runtime etc but for various reasons I wish to use some alternative configurations.  How do I tell the compilation task about these configurations?  The documentation seems to suggest that it can be set on the sourceset using compileClasspath but I'm unclear how exactly this is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do:

```
sourceSets {
   main {
      compileClasspath = configuration.myConf 
      // or compileClasspath += configurations.myConf
   }
}
```

You can also have a look at the sample at GRADLE_HOME/samples/java/withIntegrationTests to see how the classpaths of a source set are configured.

Hans

--
Hans Dockter
 
Founder, Gradle
http://www.gradle.org, http://twitter.com/gradleorg
CEO, Gradle Inc. - Gradle Training, Support, Consulting
http://www.gradle.biz

Comment: I'm still have some issues with gradle complaining about "Circular dependency between tasks" however that may be specific to my build so I might raise this in the mailing list.